# ABGroupAddMember returns false. Why?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, addressbook

When I call `ABRecordRef aRecord = ABPersonCreate()`, `ABGroupAddMember()`  returns `YES`.

But when I use ABNewPersonViewController

```
- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonViewController didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
```

And use the `(ABRecordRef)person to ABGroupAddMember()`,  it returns `NO`.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Set the `addressBook` property of the `ABNewPersonViewController` to the address book reference, which you use to retrieve the group reference.
If you don't set the `addressBook` property before the `ABNewPersonViewController` is displayed, then it will create its own address book reference and the `ABGroupAddMember` function will not work.